# Zimbra Login authentication error with external LDAP

Tags: ldap, zimbra

I'm trying to login Zimbra using **external LDAP** which is ***openLDAP***. When I test login authentication using Zimbra Administration console, test is successful. But I can't login Zimbra using Web client. Getting an error like this:

> The username or password is incorrect. Verify that CAPS LOCK is not on, and then retype the current username and password.`

Answer (score 0):

Use Bind DN like Username@domain.inc

Answer (score 0):

The username or password is incorrect. Verify that CAPS LOCK is not on, and then retype the current username and password.

Comment: It is general message for login feature. what is new

Answer (score 0):

I recently was configuring zimbra with external ldap. Got same error. I dig a little and found messages about account not found in mailbox.log. Later I found [this post made by PhD](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4790&start=10#p133979) on zimbra forum:

> Yes that right... as zimbra uses its own internal ldap system for user accounts and system settings...
>
> external ldap auth is just that... used for password authentication - but it still requires a valid user account in zimbra to authenticate with

So it looks like you have to first create user account in zimbra and after that you can log in with password from external ldap.

I'm not sure if there is a fix/solution to this situation - a way to configure zimbra such that admin do not have to create accounts in zimbra manually.